# proving a set is a group

Tags: group-theory, binary-operations

I'm stuck at the final stage of a problem and could use some help.

Let the binary operation * on the naturals N be an Abelian group (i.e also complies with a*b = b*a for every a and b of N)
It is known that 2 is the identity element and that 3 is inverse to 1.

N has a new binary operation Δ defined on it as such:
aΔb = (a * 1)*b for every a,b ∈ N
prove that N with Δ is a group.

I have been successful in showing closure, associativity, and the existence of the identity element which turns out to be e = 3.

I am stuck at the last requirement of proving the existence of an inverse element for each element.

Basically I need to prove that for every a ∈ N there is a b ∈ N
 such that a Δ b = 3 
 so then (a * 1)* b = 3
 but I have no idea how to isolate b

I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element $(a*1)$ has an inverse under $*$; let's call it $c$. Then
$b=c*3$ works.

This is a special case of a general set-up. Take a group $G$ (not necessarily Abelian)
with
operation $*$. Fix $g_0\in G$ and define $\circ$ on $G$ by
$$a\circ b=a*g_0*b.$$
Then $G$ is also a group under the operation $\circ$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I spent hours trying to express b with the limited information about *. when in fact all that was needed to show that it exists.